is there a better shorthand for toggling the existance of an item inside an array?
I often have to check if an item is part of an array. If it is, I would like to remove it. If it's not, then it should be added. Essentially its toggling the existence of a given item in the array.
const onDateSelected = function (date) {
  const inArray = selectedDates.value.find((d) => d === date) !== undefined;
  if (inArray) {
    selectedDates = selectedDates.filter((d) => d !== date);
  } else {
    selectedDates.push(date);
  }
};

Is there a shorter / quicker way to do this?

Hello! Does it have to be an array or can it be a set? Sets are much more amenable to the kind of operation you seem to want.

If it's something you are going to use a lot, then make it a function or an extension on array (most people recommend against doing this) then you can do something like toggleArrayItem(selectedDate, date) which is probably the shortest you'll get.  The actual implementation then doesn't need to be "short" - efficient yes, but characters of code won't matter as you only write it once.

@fdomn-m yes, I'd recommend doing this. Make it a function. Done. Then you don't have to deal with the fallout of modifying built-ins.

Using a Set makes this a lot easier using has, delete and add:


const data =  new Set([ 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar' ]);
const removeOrAdd = 'bar';

if (data.has(removeOrAdd)) {
    data.delete(removeOrAdd)
} else {
    data.add(removeOrAdd)
}

console.log([...data]);




If you really need an array, consider using indexOf combined with splice


const data = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar' ];
const removeOrAdd = 'bar';

const possibleIndex = data.indexOf(removeOrAdd);

if (possibleIndex > -1) {
    data.splice(possibleIndex, 1);
} else {
    data.push(removeOrAdd);
}

console.log(data);




True, but since op uses find((d) => d === date) I assume he's using non-object arrays.

Yeah, somehow I read the question three times and each time read that as looking up an object :/ I'd blame the heat. Set makes perfect sense here.

You can try this :
const onDateSelected = function(date) {
  const index = selectedDates.indexOf(date);
  index !== -1 ? selectedDates.splice(index, 1) : selectedDates.push(date);
};

